# why my database file in SQLite manager can not be openned?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to open my database file using "Questoid SQLite Manager". When I'm trying to do that a message says: "Select db file in File Explorer, and open it in SQLite Manager..."
As I've searched about this error, I've find that the database must have .db extension. now my database name is mydb.db and it's running on emulator.
Most of topics about this error are referring to .db extension and root permission as I've seen in these topics:
[Not able to open database file in SQLite manager plugin for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807036/not-able-to-open-database-file-in-sqlite-manager-plugin-for-eclipse)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177467/not-able-to-open-the-db-file-with-questoid-sqlite-manager-browser
[Why I can't see DB structure by SQLite Manager in file explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470749/why-i-cant-see-db-structure-by-sqlite-manager-in-file-explorer)

What else I should do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with "sqlitemanager": only .db-Database files are accepted.

This is the solution:

1. Download this Questoid SqLiteBrowser: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/com.questoid/com.questoid.sqlitebrowser_1.2.0.jar.zip
2. Unzip and put it into eclipse/dropins (not Plugins)

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser to open your database file.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to open it using firefox.
there is a plugin needed for it to do so
check [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)